# What configuration can be done on prometheus adapter in order to get the sum of cpu_usage_seconds_total accross all replicas of a container?

Tags: kubernetes, scale, prometheus, hpa

I have a Kubernetes cluster and Prometheus/Prometheus adapter installed.

This is the prometheus adapter configuration rules:

```
rules:
  custom:
  - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"container_cpu_usage_seconds_total"}'
    resources:
      overrides:
      template: "<<.Resource>>"
#          namespace:
#            resource: namespace
#          pod:
#            resource: pod
    name:
      matches: "container_cpu_usage_seconds_total"
      as: "my_custom_metric"
    metricsQuery: sum(<<.Series>>{container="php-apache"}) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
```

And this is my hpa configuration:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: php-apache
  spec:
scaleTargetRef:
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 kind: Deployment
 name: php-apache
minReplicas: 1
maxReplicas: 6
metrics:
- type: Pods
  pods:
    metric:
      name: my_custom_metric
    target:
      type: Value
      averageValue: 250 //limit
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-apache
  labels:
    run: php-apache
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    run: php-apache
```

The problem here is that I want to scale based on the summary of the replicas that `container=php-apache` use and not with the Average Value of them.

This is the value that is returned from the Prometheus Adapter:

```
{
  "kind": "MetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/%2A/malakas"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "describedObject": {
        "kind": "Pod",
        "namespace": "default",
        "name": "php-apache-d4cf67d68-8ddbx",
        "apiVersion": "/v1"
      },
      "metricName": "my_custom_metric",
      "timestamp": "2021-04-16T10:52:02Z",
      "value": "331827m",
      "selector": null
    },
    {
      "describedObject": {
        "kind": "Pod",
        "namespace": "default",
        "name": "php-apache-d4cf67d68-zxkrd",
        "apiVersion": "/v1"
      },
      "metricName": "my_custom_metric",
      "timestamp": "2021-04-16T10:52:02Z",
      "value": "44478m",
      "selector": null
    }
  ]
}
```

In this example, there are 2 replicas.
I want to get one result (the sum of these two) and not two results just like above in order to pass the result to hpa and scale accordingly.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome! Have you taken a stab at trying to figure this out yourself? Or if you have, it would make the question clearer if you shared that and any output where you're not getting what you want.

Comment: OK, is it OK now?

Answer (score 0):

You should use metrics from the service not from the pod:

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/services/*/my_custom_metric"
```